# Short story about post-apocalyptic cats

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, post-apocalyptic

I read a short story as a child. A nuclear war has happened and the protagonists are satellites/computers. They chat and plan and think they have human survivors who they nurture and help only to discover at the end that it is cats they have saved who now walk on two legs into the new world.

Comment: Armeowgeddon???

Comment: It almost sounds like Andre Norton's [*Breed to Come,*](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/462481.Breed_to_Come) but I don't think that's it; I don't recall anything about satellites or computers.

Comment: OP could explore this list of works tagged [cats, post-apocalyptic](https://www.librarything.com/tag/cats,+post-apocalyptic)

Comment: @buzz - Please don't make worthless edits.